# socket Почему получаю данные только один раз?

Tags: python, сокет

Нашёл где то пример работы сокета, клиент - сервер и хотел попробовать что то своё сделать, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, что он только один раз отвечает на запрос. При выборе ответа(1 или 2) он уже не шлёт данные. На сервер запрос попадает

- **client**

  ```
   from random import randint
   import socket
   import ast


   def db(name):
           soc.send(f"{[name]}".encode())
           data = soc.recv(1024).decode()
           print(data)

           return ast.literal_eval(data)

   class Game:
           def __init__(self, name):
                   self.name = name
                   db(self.name)
                   Game.menu(self)

           def menu(self):
                   while 1:
                           a = int(input("1) начать игру\n2)Посмотреть статистику: "))

                           elif a == 2:
                                   Game.CheckLog(self)


           def CheckLog(self):
                   data = db(self.name)
                   print(f"Игр: {data[1]}")
                   if len(ast.literal_eval(data[3])) == 0:
                           return

                   poptk = 0
                   count = 0
                   for i in ast.literal_eval(data[3]):
                           poptk += i[1]
                           count += 1
                           print(f"Игра №{i[0]} | Попыток: {i[1]} | Загаданное число: {i[2]}")

                   print(f"Ср.Кол-во попыток: {round(poptk/count, 1)}")

   soc = socket.socket()
   soc.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8989))

   Game("merka")
  ```
- **server**

  ```
   import socket
   import ast
   import sqlite3

   conn = sqlite3.connect("games.db") # или :memory:
   cursor = conn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("DROP TABLE users")
   cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE users(name INTEGER, games INTEGER, atmps INTEGER, log STRING, RandomNumber INTEGER);")
   conn.commit()


   soc = socket.create_server(("127.0.0.1", 8989))
   soc.listen(100)

   while True:
           try: con, addr = soc.accept()

           except socket.error:
                   pass

           else:
                   data = con.recv(1024).decode()

                   data = ast.literal_eval(data)

                   if len(data) == 1:
                           cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users where name="{data[0]}"')
                           if cursor.fetchone()==None:
                                   cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{data[0]}', '0', '0', '[]', '100')")#вводит все данные об участнике в БД
                                   conn.commit()
                           cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users where name="{data[0]}"')
                           con.send((f"{cursor.fetchone()}").encode())

                   elif len(data) == 5:
                           cursor.execute(f'UPDATE users SET games={data[1]}, atmps={data[2]}, log={data[3]}, RandomNumber={data[4]} where name={data[0]}')
                           conn.commit()
  ```

В чём проблемка может быть?

Comment: Всё что в цикле `while True:` хорошо бы в `try/except` обернуть, ведь упасть код может много где.

Comment: @CrazyElf server обёрнут, но что бы в клиенте упал код, надо что бы он заработал)

Comment: Где же он обёрнут то? Весь блок `else:` никак не защищён от падения

Comment: else да, но он не падаёт

Comment: Кто вам это гарантирует?

Comment: в любом случае, ошибки пока не вылетают.

Answer (score 0):

Просто вы неправильно эти данные принимаете. Если посмотреть описание функции recv, то она возвращает реально принятые данные, которые могут быть порезаны. В вашем случае нужно в цикле принимать данные, пока не будет достигнута нужная длина. А еще лучше, сделать заголовок, в котором будет храниться длина пакета, сначала принимаете заголовок, потом в цикле принимаете данные на нужную длину. Tcp гарантирует, что данные не перемешаются и будут приходить последовательно, но протокол не гарантирует, что данные будут приходить ровно теми же самыми кусками, которыми они были отправлены.